# Allow a subclass's function to specify a sub-type without breaking Liskov substitution

Tags: python, inheritance, abstract-class

I have an abstract base class, and I want its subclasses to specify an input type *among a set of input types*. For example, if I have another ABC `TaxForm` that `W2TaxForm` is a subclass of:

```py
class TaxPreparer(ABC):
  @abstractmethod
  def file(self, x: TaxForm):
    # do something with the iterable

class IncomeTaxPreparer(TaxPreparer):
  def file(self, x: W2TaxForm):
    # do something
```

I know this violates the Liskov substitution principle, so I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this than just ignoring it. My rationale for doing this: my outside function knows what type of `TaxForm` it's dealing, but I want to be able to write generic code where an instance of `TaxPreparer` is able to call its `.file` function on the TaxForm without specifying what subclass of `TaxPreparer` I am using. At the same time, I want my `IncomeTaxPreparer.file` method to know it's dealing with a `W2TaxForm` so that it can call specific methods and properties that the more general `TaxForm` lacks.

Is there a way to do this? E.g. to specify in the abstract method definition for `file` that I want `x` to be some subclass of `TaxForm` that willl be specified by the subclass?

Comment: Have you tried using the visitor pattern?

Comment: LSP is not a syntactic but a semantic principle. So if your code is structured such that it semantically makes sense to break LSP, I don't see any reason why you should try and fit a square peg into a round hole.

Comment: What is the visitor pattern? I'm not familiar with it. 

Since I use mypy I'm getting an error message on this. I don't want to silence it because my desire is to obey the rules of my superclass (e.g. the input argument must be a subclass of TaxForm) which the error messages should help ensure I do.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I have decided to use Generic classes from mypy!